# Create a class which accept Runnable but include better control

Tags: java

I want to create a structured code like this:

```
EventWrapper.newWrapper().
    ifThen(isSunday(), 
            () -> announceSunday()).
    pauseFor(Duration.ofSeconds(10)).
    addAsyn(() -> System.out.println("Asynch System out")),
    add(() -> System.out.println("Sync System out")).execute();
```

I want to have multiple functions such as
pauseFor which pause the execution of this Wrapper, addAsyn which execute a runnable but using a threadpool, add which execute the runnable but others wait until the content of the runnable is executed and ifThen which accept a boolean condition and execute the given runnable if true.

My code so far base on a previous post i made here (and thank you very much) is the following:

```
public class EventWrapper
{
    private final List<Runnable> _wrappers = new ArrayList<>();

    public EventWrapper add(final Runnable runnable)
    {
        _wrappers.add(runnable);
        return this;
    }

    public void execute()
    {
        _wrappers.forEach(Runnable::run);
    }

    public static EventWrapper newWrapper()
    {
        return new EventWrapper();
    }
}
```

Is there any idea on how to add these functions in this class and while execute it to be able to control the way i mentioned? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe just use `CompletableFuture`? No need to reinvent wheels.

Comment: Hm, I think this particular question is too broad and not easily answerable. How are the chained method calls interpreted? Like a series of actions executed as soon as they're reached or should everything be configured and executed once the actual `execute` method is called? At first glance it seems like it might be doable with a queue paired with some sort of command pattern maybe? But have a look at [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html). It already offers methods for composing such complex behavior.

Comment: I agree that this is too broad. Please attempt to solve the problem yourself, and then if you have some issues with your solution, you can ask a more focused question here on Stack Overflow.